# How to know at which points this function is continuous?

Tags: continuity

For the function:
$f(x)= \begin{cases}
      x^2 & \mbox{if }x \mbox{ is rational } \\
      -x^2 & \mbox{if }x \mbox{ is irrational } \\
\end{cases}$

I am looking for points where it is continuous
My thought is that this function is not continuous for any number except 0 since if we consider a point $x_{0}$ in $R$, then since both rational and irrational numbers are dense we can find a sequence of rational numbers ${a_{n}}$ and a sequence of irrational numbers ${b_{n}}$ that converge to $x_{0}$, and then we have $x_{0}^2 = -x_{0}^2$, which is only true for $x_{0} = 0$
Am I missing something here?

Comment: For me seems fine, if you finish editing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you did is almost fine. I say almost because your proof is convincing regarding the fact that $f$ is discontinuous at any $x_0 \neq 0$.

However, you've not proven that $f$ is continuous at $0$. Which is however easy to see as you have for any $x \in (-1, 1)$

$$\lvert f(x) \rvert \le x^2 \le \lvert x \rvert.$$

Comment: Proof of continuity in $0$ is done by Heine in last $4$ lines.

Comment: @zkutch I don't understand your comment. If you refer to the last 4 lines of the question, then it is not sufficient as Heine supposes that you consider **all** sequences.

Comment: **All** sequences can be obtained in following way: let's consider arbitrary one. It contain infinite number of rational members, or infinite number of irrational members, or infinite number of both. In any variant we need mentioned property $x_{0}^2 = -x_{0}^2$. And this one is true only for $x_0=0$. This standard type of reasoning in such cases and this is why I thought that the questioner meant such consideration.

Comment: @zkutch To prove continuity at zero using Heine, you need to prove that for any sequence $\{x_n\}$ converging to zero, $\{f(x_n)\}$ converges to zero. And I don't see how the consideration $x_0^2=-x_0^2$ proves that. It only proves that the only possible continuity point is at zero. Not that $f$ is indeed continuous at zero. You need to add arguments for that.

Comment: Add to already written by me $x_n \to x_0$ . Then given consideration of subsequences and brought equality shows continuity for $x_0=0$ and discontinuity for $x_0 \ne 0$.